# 'negative examples' for spacy NER transfer learning?

Tags: nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I want to train the spacy v2 NER model on my own labels, for which I crawled some text from different webpages. Coming with the crawling, there's of course lots of text that is just garbage and don't contain any information, but fortunately in most cases it's the exact same text because it's crawled from some news feed that is integrated in the webpages.

So my question is, can I use the 'garbage part' of the crawled text as some sort of negative example for the model to learn? That is, does it make sense not to annotate these parts of the crawled texts and feed it to the model so that the model learns not to annotate these kind of examples? Otherwise I would have to filter out these examples manually for my train/test set which I obviously cannot do, when the model is in production and has to work fully automated

Comment: Can you provide more information about your input data and what you mean by garbage text? If it's HTML, you might benefit from parsing the page with something like Beautiful Soup (https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: My objective is to extract a short summary about companies for which I have an excel list with over thousand of company URLs. The summary should be on the level of e.g. company, num. of employees and keywords. Currently I extract the links with jusText that removes boilerplate content, however there's still much text that contains no information for my objective. For example many of the pages share the same template and this template contains a rss feed that unfortunately gets also crawled. Therefore I was thinking of feeding this repetitive rss feed text one time for training but without labe